# Need help to understand pointer declaration in c language

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

What's the difference between the following types of pointer declarations in c language?

```
int *p(int a),
int (*p)(int a),
int *(*p)(it(*a)[]),
```

It would be very useful if some examples are added for proper explanation.

Comment: Try https://cdecl.org/ and type the expression without the `a` Example: `int *(*p)(int(*)[])`

Comment: The only thing you have to know about the third one is to never use it. If you do, you will possibly get fired right after the code review.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *p(int a);
```

I strongly doubt it's a pointer declaration. If it's written better you may be able to understand that it's a **function** that takes an `int` and returns a pointer to a `int`.

---

```
int (*p)(int a);
```

A basic function pointer. `p` points to a function taking an `int` and returning an `int`. For example:

```
int foo(int x) { return x+1; }
p = &foo;
```

---

The last one is a bit complex because it's invalid. There should have been a number inside the brackets. I assume it's corrected (including a typo) as below.

```
int *(*p)(int(*a)[3]);
```

It's a function pointer, the function takes a pointer to an array of 3 `int`s, and return a pointer to `int`. For example:

```
int *extract_first(int (*a)[3]) {
    return (*a);
}
p = &extract_first;
```

Comment: Are you sure about the need for adding `3`? I don't think it is correct for C but only for C++

Answer (score 1):

The first is fa function declaration, it takes an int and returns a pointer-to-int,
The second is a pointer-to-function taking an int and returning an int
If the third should have been:

```
int * (*p) (int(*a)[]);
```

It is a pointer-to-function taking a pointer-to-an-array-of-int and returning an pointer-to-int.